What are examples of statistically confirmed LLM functions?
I am looking for examples from research of highly statistically reliable LLM functions. So instead of using an LLM in a general purpose way, an exact, replicable LLM setup where it is guaranteed to do a very precise function, say something LLM related, with a known accuracy of like, 98% or something. I am looking for research articles.

highly statistically reliable LLM functions = tasks where LLMs almost always perform perfectly?
